# Is it possible to change an existing post status from 'pending' to 'publish' via email?

Tags: email, post-status, notifications

I am building a website which uses a custom form plugin, and the plugin gives me the ability to create posts (pending or published) using the data from the form. Upon submission of the form, I want a specific list of people to receive an email notification of the pending post to review, which they can approve (update post status to 'publish') in one click. Any ideas?

Currently, my workaround is to forward the email to an email address that I am using for posting, but it's a clunky solution.

Comment: You could post to an endpoint or maybe `admin-ajax.php` - is this something that multiple people need to agree to publish or if just one from the group wants to publish it pushes to publish?

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1 - Register a Custom Query Var

By adding a custom query var, you make WP aware of it so it can be used in requests.

```
function wpse_add_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'wpse_set_to_publish';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_add_query_vars' );
```

## Step 2 - Sniff The Request

Now we hook into `parse_request` to look for our new custom query var. This is where you process it and it can get as complicated or simple as you want. For example, for security, you could check for the existence of a token that is stored as postmeta or a transient. But at it's most basic level:

```
function wpse_sniff_request( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && isset( $query->query_vars['wpse_set_to_publish'] ) ) {
        $post_vars = array(
            'ID' => $query->query_vars['wpse_set_to_publish'],
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );
        wp_update_post( $post_vars );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse_sniff_request' );
```

*Note: you could also skip step one and do this step in an `init` hook and instead intercept `$_GET['wpse_set_to_publish']` but it's not exactly the "Wordpress way"*

## Step 3 - Provide an Approval Link in Email

Finally, assuming you're generating the email that goes out, you can include a link with something along these lines:

`echo add_query_arg( array( 'wpse_set_to_publish' => $post_id ), site_url() );`

*Note: You'll probably get the `$post_id` from the return value of `wp_insert_post()`.*

Then, once the person clicks on that link, it should take them to `http://yourwebsite.com/?wpse_set_to_publish=123` and this will update the post with the ID of `123` to having a status of publish.

Unfortunately I don't have time to fully test this right now, but this should get you steered in the right direction. Again, this is *the most basic* implementation and you should always consider security, permissions, etc. While this also might be more convenient, it would theoretically be a lot more secure if you just provide a link to [`get_edit_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_edit_post_link) which would force the user to log in (if they weren't already), then they could move right to publish from the admin.